# Find the index of an object in an array in Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [flash as3 - how do I find an object's index in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093166/flash-as3-how-do-i-find-an-objects-index-in-an-array)

I have an array of objects similar to:

```
[
    {
        start : 0.000,
        end   : 0.100
    },
    {
        start : 0.100,
        end   : 0.200
    },
    {
        start : 0.200,
        end   : 0.300
    }
]
```

Is there a quick way for me to query this object frame after frame to find out where a value (in this case the current time of a audio playback) lies?

After chatting with my coworkers, they have suggested I enumerate this into a large array of indexed values with references to which index they are associated with, for instance

```
[000] = 0
[001] = 0
...
[100] = 1
...
[200] = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexing strategy would be the fastest, however don't you need to do it more like this?:

```
["0.000"] = {};
["0.100"] = {};
```

Alternatively you can loop through and select the relevant object in your first example, assuming that there's no more than say 1000 objects in your Array it should be more than fast enough:

```
function find(start:Number):int
{
    for each(var i:Object in yourArray)
    {
        if(i.start == start) return yourArray.indexOf(i);
    }
}
```

This should return the index of an object with the specified start time:

```
trace(find(0.1)); // 1
```

Comment: To keep memory usage lower I would only enumerate with an index id, then look into the actual config object for the relevant information. I think I'm just going to have to try both options out and do some benchmarks on which performs faster.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better solution would be to use a `Dictionary` [(link)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html).

Dictionaries are fast and easy ways to store associative data.

Though I'm not entirely sure what problem you're trying to solve, so other data types may be more appropriate for you.  I'm just letting you know of another option you have available to you.

Comment: this looks interesting but i'm not sure if it's going to work any faster than enumerating into an array. maybe i'm just not understanding it properly.